# Debezium Connect image version 2.2 is not accessible in Azure Container Instance

Tags: azure, docker, terraform

I am trying to create an Azure Container Instance with Debezium Connect using Terraform. When I use the Debezium Connect version 1.6.0, the container group deploys successfully. However, when I try to use the latest version (2.2) or the "latest" tag, I encounter the following error:

> Error: creating Container Group (Subscription:
> "subscription_id>" Resource Group Name:
> "Resource_Name" Container Group Name: "ci-example-debezium"):
> performing ContainerGroupsCreateOrUpdate:
> containerinstance.ContainerInstanceClient#ContainerGroupsCreateOrUpdate:
> Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error:
> Code="InaccessibleImage" Message="The image 'debezium/connect:2.2' in
> container group 'ci-example-debezium' is not accessible. Please check
> the image and registry credential."

```
resource "azurerm_container_group" "debezium" {
  # Configuration...
  containers {
    name   = "debezium"
    image  = "debezium/connect:2.2"
    # Rest of the container configuration...
  }
  # Rest of the azurerm_container_group configuration...
}
```

I've verified that the image is available on Docker Hub: https://hub.docker.com/r/debezium/connect/tags

Why am I encountering this error with the latest version of Debezium Connect? Are there any changes or additional configurations required for using version 2.2 or the "latest" tag?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you using it with hdinsights or event hubs?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio using Debezium with Azure Event Hubs

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think Azure Event Hubs Kafka Connect is not compatible with Kafka 3.4 which is the one debezium connect 2.0 is trying to use.

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio so this compatibility issue will not even let the image download?

Comment: my bad, I was thinking about something else. It looks like is auth issue against docker hub. Can you run it locally ?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio I can, I ran docker pull debezium/connect:latest locally on a shell window and it worked fine. That was my first test. How do you go about the auth issue?

Comment: try setting the image as "image  = "hub.docker.com/debezium/connect:2.2"

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio I tried what you recommended as well as connect:latest, still same error

Answer (score 0):

As you removed part of the configuration, I think it's missing a piece where you specify the credentials to authenticate on Docker hub:

```
  image_registry_credential {
    server   = "hub.docker.com"
    username = "yourusername1"
    password = "yourpassword"
  }
```

Your tf file will look more or less like this:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "${var.prefix}-resources"
  location = "${var.location}"
}

resource "azurerm_container_group" "example" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-continst"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.example.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.example.name}"
  ip_address_type     = "public"
  os_type             = "linux"

  image_registry_credential {
    server   = "hub.docker.com"
    username = "yourusername1"
    password = "yourpassword"
  }

  container {
    name   = "debezium"
    image  = "debezium/connect:2.2"
    cpu    = "2"
    memory = "4"
  }


  tags = {
    environment = "testing"
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought about this but since we are using the public Debezium image from Docker Hub, which does not require any authentication or additional setup why would this be needed? I can see this working if we were using a private image or an image hosted in a private registry.

Comment: can you give it a try and let me know if it works? Even for pulling images from docker hub, a docker login is required. I think under the hood, azure is caching some token which is expired, reason why it's failing

Comment: did not work, still same issue with " Please check the image and registry credential."

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use  "quay.io/debezium/connect:latest" and that worked

https://debezium.io/blog/2023/04/25/container-images-quayio/